# Инициализация константы в шаблонном классе

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, c++14, c++17

```
enum class E { e0, e1, e2, };

template <int S>
class C {
    static const E _e = (S == 1 ? E::e0 : S == 123 ? E::e1 : E::e2);
};
```

Можно ли поле _e задать через switch/case или еще как нибудь, если у меня enum имеет много значений?

Comment: Так а чем именно вас не устроил `?:`?

Comment: "у меня enum имеет много значений"

Comment: И? Какая разница: много значений в `switch` или много значений в `?:`? Вы уперлись в лимиты компилятора для `?:`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вынести логику в функцию, или в лямбду:

```cpp
static constexpr E _e = []{
    ...
    return ...;
}();
```

Answer (score 4):

Ну, если нужен `switch` - [почему бы и нет](http://ideone.com/dJ07Kh)?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum class E { e0, e1, e2, e3, };

static constexpr E get(int S)
{
    switch(S)
    {
    case 0: return E::e0;
    case 1: return E::e1;
    case 2: return E::e2;
    default: return E::e3;
    }
}

template <int S>
class C {
public:
    static const E e = get(S);
    void out() const { cout << "e = " << int(e) << endl; }

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    C<1>().out();
    C<2>().out();
    C<123>().out();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно определить шаблонный обьект и соответствующие специализации:

```
enum class E { e0, e1, e2, edef};

template <int S>
constexpr E e = E::edef;

template<>
constexpr E e<1> = E::e0;
template<>
constexpr E e<2> = E::e1;
template<>
constexpr E e<12> = E::e2;

template <int S>
struct C {
    static const E _e = e<S>;
};
```

и если  `S` имеет значение различное от перечисленных, то `e<S>  == E::edef`